# d3 pan/zoom dynamically locking x/y axis with shift and ctrl keys

Tags: javascript, d3.js

We have a requirement where we want to modify the d3 zoom behaviour so while the <kbd>shift</kbd> key is pressed during a pan or zoom operation the visual will only be scaled/transformed on the x axis.
Also while the <kbd>ctrl</kbd> key is pressed the visual will only be scaled/transformed on the y axis.
We do want the x/y axis to be stretched or compressed while zoom with the lock switched on.

As we want this behaviour universally in our system we have modified the `translateTo` and `scaleTo` methods in the d3.js file.
This modification does exactly want we want while the <kbd>shift</kbd>/<kbd>ctrl</kbd> is pressed but when the next zoom/pan operation without a modifier button is performed the visualisation jumps to how the view would appear without the <kbd>shift</kbd> or <kbd>ctrl</kbd> button being pressed.

I'm not sure why the display behaves like this but we're so close to getting what we need any advice or help resolving this problem would be greatly appreciated.

```
function translateTo(p, l) {
  l = point(l);

  // Note: Added by for axis lock zooming
  if (d3.event.shiftKey) {
      view.y += p[1] - l[1];
  }
  else if (d3.event.ctrlKey) {
      view.x += p[0] - l[0];
  } else {
      view.x += p[0]-l[0];
      view.y += p[1]-l[1];
  }
}
function rescale() {
    if (x1) x1.domain(x0.range().map(function (x) {
        // Note: Added for axis lock zooming
        if (d3.event.shiftKey) {
            return x;
        } else {
            return (x - view.x) / view.k;
        }
  }).map(x0.invert));
    if (y1) y1.domain(y0.range().map(function (y) {
        // Note: Added for axis lock zooming
        if (d3.event.ctrlKey) {
            return y;
        } else {
            return (y - view.y) / view.k;
        }
  }).map(y0.invert));
}
```

Comment: The zoom behaviour keeps track of what changes internally, so you have to modify this in addition to the actual visible changes.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply Lars. Any quick pointers on how/where to update the internal variables that retain the changes.

Comment: In the zoom handler, update `zoom.translate()` accordingly.